# Very confused on how to put PHP code into HTML

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I have a HTML file that contains this code

```
<head></head>
<body class="page_bg">
Hello, today is <?php echo date('l, F jS, Y'); ?>.
</body>
</html>
```

and I am wondering why when I run it only says `"Hello today i"`. Without the date. After some research I saw I had to add a .htaccess file with the code `AddType application/x-httpd-php .html` inside, yet it still only writes `"Hello today is  ."` did I save the .htaccess filethe wrong place or is it something else?

I saved it in in a folder called `PHP and HTML test` the HTML file and the .htaccess file are both in the same place. I installed PHP with XAMPP.

Comment: Have you saved your html/php file as `.php`?

Comment: no i saved as .html

Comment: you must save it as .php and run through your local server

Comment: not a .php file

Comment: How are you accessing the file, via alocal url: `http://localhost/some-folder/page.html` oir file path `c:\user\qwertykey\some-folder\page.html`? You need to use the former

Comment: i saved the file as .php but how would i open it?

Comment: localhost/filname.php

Comment: type in browser

Comment: I have apache i got it with XAMPP

Comment: So are you accessing a url or a filepath?? What does the address bar in your browser contain

Comment: Save this file as .php and store in your `htdocs` folder, then access it as `localhost/filename.php`

Comment: is ht docs loacted in XAMPP

Comment: By default `C:\xampp\htdocs` - it's what's known as the *document root* - you can set it to anything you like once you know your way around Apache conf files.

Comment: @ Akintunde  i put http://localhost/index.php into the browser and it didn't work

Comment: `http://localhost/index.php` will point to *document root* > index.php ... probably `C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php` - is that where your file is (since you stated *"I saved it in in a folder called PHP and HTML test"*)

Comment: that doesn't work... XAMPP is saved on the desktop

Comment: does Apache need to be active

Comment: You need to install it then load it up, yes. It gets Apache (and MySQL) running - without which you've got no web server.

Comment: there is an error whenever i try to run it...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your file is saved as `.php` then run the file through a server. Php cannot run any other way. I use Webstorm which simplifies the process but a quick google search can show you how to setup a localhost server through PHP. Something like `php -S localhost:8000` would work, just make sure your PATH (if on windows) has the installation path to PHP.

Comment: *Technically* `AddType application/x-httpd-php .html` *should* tell the server to treat `.html` files as PHP so you'd not need to rename it to `.php` ... I'd argue that's bad practice mind as it means Apache has to use the PHP interpreter on bog standard HTML pages but that's beside the point.